# Java: How to find number of meet word in file?

Tags: java, multithreading, frequency

Program need to find if word is in file. If this search was success would show frequency of meet word in file. But this don't work correctly, matches isn't true.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class FolderScan implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
            File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.path = path;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FolderScan() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findFiles(path);
        queue.add(endOfWorkFile);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void findFiles(String path) {

        try {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class FileScan implements Runnable {

    private String whatFind;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    public FileScan(String whatFind, BlockingQueue<File> queue,
            CountDownLatch latch, File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FileScan() {
    }

    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                File file;
                file = queue.take();

                if (file == endOfWorkFile) {
                    break;
                }

                scan(file);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void scan(File file) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int matches = 0;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        if (words.contains(this.whatFind)) {
            matches++;
        }

        String myStr = String.format("File: %s - and the number of matches "
                + "is: %d", file.getAbsolutePath(), matches);
        System.out.println(myStr);
    }

    // ask user about input
    public void askUserPathAndWord() {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path;
        String whatFind;
        BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {

                File endOfWorkFile = new File("GameOver.tmp");
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

                FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(path, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);
                FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(whatFind, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);

                Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                executor.execute(folderScan);
                executor.execute(fileScan);

                latch.await();
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        new FileScan().askUserPathAndWord();

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\nRuntime time " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
    }
}
```

Questions:

- How to solve this trouble and organize this find in file correctly?
- Maybe better to use another logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a problem:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next();
    words.add(word);
}

if (words.contains(this.whatFind)) {
    matches++;
}
```

This only checks if the word exists, not how many occurrences of the word there are.

Change it to:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String word = scanner.next();
    if (word.equals(whatFind))
        matches++;
}
```

or more simply:

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
    if (scanner.next().equals(whatFind))
        matches++;
```

Comment: How we can chech here `if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt") queue.put(currentFile);` - MIME type? Coz I don't know how this to do.

Comment: @NazarRoskolnikov `endsWith(".mime")`? Not sure whether it's limited to that extension. Not sure if there exists non-plain-text versions of this extension, if so, you'll need a specific parser for that, which can be quite complicated.

Comment: this `endsWith(".mime")` don't work. I used your `simpler` variant - correctly work. How we can print, only if whatFind is in this file?

Comment: @NazarRoskolnikov `if (matches > 0) { String myStr = ... }`

Answer (score 1):

**After some advices (Dukeling Thanks you a lot!):**

```
package task;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class FolderScan implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
            File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.path = path;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FolderScan() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findFiles(path);
        queue.add(endOfWorkFile);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void findFiles(String path) {

        try {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                        queue.put(currentFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class FileScan implements Runnable {

    private String whatFind;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    public FileScan(String whatFind, BlockingQueue<File> queue,
            CountDownLatch latch, File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FileScan() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                File file;
                file = queue.take();

                if (file == endOfWorkFile) {
                    break;
                }

                scan(file);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void scan(File file) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int matches = 0;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (scanner.hasNext())
            if (scanner.next().equals(whatFind)) {
                matches++;
            }

        if (matches > 0) {
            String myStr = String.format(
                    "File: %s - and the number of matches " + "is: %d",
                    file.getAbsolutePath(), matches);
            System.out.println(myStr);
        }
    }

    // ask user about input
    public void askUserPathAndWord() {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path;
        String whatFind;
        BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {

                File endOfWorkFile = new File("GameOver.tmp");
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

                FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(path, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);
                FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(whatFind, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);

                Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                executor.execute(folderScan);
                executor.execute(fileScan);

                latch.await();
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        new FileScan().askUserPathAndWord();

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("\nRuntime time " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
```

Choose a data structure of List implementation.

Place the following if in the while loop itself.

```
 if (words.contains(this.whatFind)) {
        matches++;
    }
```